# How to make "cd ..." goup two directories?

Tags: macos, terminal, alias, cd

So, currently on macOS I have aliases set up like this...

```
alias ...='cd ../..'
alias ....='cd ../../..'
```

This allows me to go up multiple directories by typing in `...` in my terminal. However, in my previous setup, I had it so typing in `cd ...` would go up multiple directories. I'm trained to write `cd` in the beginning... how do I change my aliases for it to work the way I desire?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941338/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-shell-alias your problem can be solved like this:

```
alias cd='function _cd(){ cd ${1/.../..\/..}; }; _cd '
```

The parameter expansion in the function replaces all occurrences of '...' by '../..', thus it is not a really clean solution, but I think it may still be acceptable or can be improved.

Comment: This actually works quite nicely. I'm not sure how or why, but this works for `cd ..`, `cd ...`, `cd ....`, and `cd .....` (I haven't tried for more than 5 dots, but this is all I need :-D )

Comment: I'm confused. On my system (MacOs Mojave, bash version 3.2.57), only `cd ...` works. With 4 dots I get, as expected, the error message `-bash: cd: ../...: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have an alias name with spaces. To do what you want with aliases you need to take advantage of this property:

> If the value of the alias replacing the word ends in a <blank>, the shell shall check the next command word for alias substitution; this process shall continue until a word is found that is not a valid alias or an alias value does not end in a <blank>.

([source](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03_01)), so `cd` *and* consecutive `...` are resolved as aliases.

You need aliases like this:

```
cd='cd '
...='../..'
....='../../..'
# and so on
```

But then if you happen to have a directory named `ls` and you type `cd ls`, then `ls` will also be prone to alias substitution. If `ls` is an alias, this will backfire.

**Pure alias approach is therefore wrong. This function will do** (use it *without* the above aliases):

```
cd() {
       if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
          command cd
       elif [ "$(printf '%s' "$1" | wc -l)" -eq 0 ]; then
          command cd "$(printf '%s' "$1" | sed '/^\.\.\+$/ {s|..|.|; s|.|../|g }')";
       else
          command cd "$1"
       fi
     }
```

(Note: to make it work in `zsh`, invoke `set -o POSIX_BUILTINS` or replace every `command` with `builtin` in the function body).

`sed` gets the argument passed to the function and changes it iff it consists of two or more dots; the tool removes the first dot and replaces every dot (that's left) with `../`.

There is additional logic:

- `[ "$#" -eq 0 ]` allows the sole `cd` (without arguments) to work as it should.
- `[ "$(printf '%s' "$1" | wc -l)" -eq 0 ]` is to prevent `sed` to alter multi-line directory names (e.g. `foo<newline>.....` which *is* a valid name). Note that for usual names (not containing newlines) `wc -l` returns `0` (not `1`, POSIX doesn't consider a "line" without terminating newline to be a line), hence we test against `0`.

And there's a quirk:

- In `s|..|.|` the first two dots are not literal dots, this is regex. One may say it should be `s|\.\.|.|` but notice `/^\.\.\+$/` ensures there are only dots in the line in the first place. The same applies to the first dot in `s|.|../|g`.

Comment: Why do you do ``printf '%s' "$1" |`` instead of ``<<< "$1"``?  Just for POSIX?

Comment: @Scott Yes, for POSIX. My first (not published) draft used `<<<`.

Comment: The function didn't work for me... normal cd just stopped working :/  It might be because I'm using zsh

Comment: @JimmyHuch Thank you for the feedback. My fix for `zsh` is now just under the function code.